# Quora says account with email address already exists, but can't find one using it when logging in

Tags: quora

I tried to use "Sign up with Facebook" for Quora, but got this message:

> There is already an account on Quora using that e-mail address. If this is your e-mail address, you can log in with it here.

[image]

So, if there should be an account with this email, I try to login with it, but it returns:

> No account found for this email. Retry, or Sign up for Quora.

What gives? Is there or is there not an account with my email? I don't remember creating one, but in the past sometimes it happened, that I created an account somewhere, and since I never used it, I just forgot about it.

Comment: Weird. I'd ping bugs@quora.com.